# Why does JSch ChannelSftp returns "Handle closed"?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using jsch 0.1.54 and I am trying to access an FTP server via SFTP. This works all properly and I am able to step to the desired directory but when I am getting files using a pattern doing a *channel.ls("*");* I only get the first match and for the next one I get a ***"Handle closed***" but not the filename. Why?

To be more precisely, when I finally reached the desired directory, I do a

```
sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + lsEntry.getFilename() +
                                        File.separator + "*", new ChannelSftp.LsEntrySelector() {...});
```

Maybe the LsEntrySelectore is the reason for the *"Handle closed"*!?

Here is the complete code of the method:

```
   public Map<String, byte[]> readFiles () {
    final Map<String, byte[]> vaFiles = new HashMap();
    final Channel channel;
    try {
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        final List<String> ftpAccounts = Arrays.stream(this.ftpAccounts).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (final String ftpAccount : ftpAccounts) {
            System.out.println(ftpAccount);
            try {
                try {
                    final SftpATTRS attrs = sftp.stat(ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // The folder ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR does not exist.
                    // Simply continue...
                    continue;
                }
                final Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + "*");
                final List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> ftpFileList = files.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                for (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry lsEntry : ftpFileList) {
                    if (lsEntry.getAttrs().isDir() &&
                        lsEntry.getFilename().equals(XXX_DIR)) {
                            sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + lsEntry.getFilename() +
                                    File.separator + "*", new ChannelSftp.LsEntrySelector() {

                                @Override
                                public int select (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry) {
                                    final Matcher mtc = pattern.matcher(entry.getFilename());
                                    final SftpATTRS attr = entry.getAttrs();
                                    if (mtc.find() && !attr.isDir() && !attr.isLink()) {
                                        System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
                                        try {
                                            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new
                                                                                       ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                            sftp.get(ftpAccount + File.separator +
                                                     XXX_DIR + File.separator + entry.getFilename(), baos);
                                            vaFiles.put(ftpAccount + File.separator +
                                                        XXX_DIR + File.separator + entry.getFilename(),
                                                    baos.toByteArray());
                                            logger.info("File " + ftpAccount + File.separator +
                                                        XXX_DIR + File.separator + entry.getFilename() + " downloaded.");
                                            baos.close();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (SftpException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("CONTINUE = " + CONTINUE);
                                    return CONTINUE;
                                }
                          });
                    }//end if
                }
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vaFiles;
}
```

Is it the way I open and close the ByteArrayOutputStream?

The exception:

```
4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1747)
    at de.postcon.SftpFileHandler.readFiles(SftpFileHandler.java:150)
    at de.postcon.VaFtp2EmMover.downloadVAFiles(VaFtp2EmMover.java:145)
    at de.postcon.VaFtp2EmMover.main(VaFtp2EmMover.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Buffer.getByte(Buffer.java:148)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Buffer.getString(Buffer.java:188)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1675)
    ... 3 more
```

Minimalizing the method's code to this:

```
public Map<String, byte[]> readFiles () {
    final Map<String, byte[]> vaFiles = new HashMap();
    final String ftpAccount = "/accumio";
    try {
        sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + TO_POSTCON_DIR + File.separator + "*", new ChannelSftp.LsEntrySelector() {

            @Override
            public int select (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry) {
                final Matcher mtc = pattern.matcher(entry.getFilename());
                final SftpATTRS attr = entry.getAttrs();
                if (mtc.find() && !attr.isDir() && !attr.isLink()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
                }
                System.out.println("CONTINUE = " + CONTINUE);
                return CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vaFiles;
}
```

...it's working. Thus, the problem seems to be produced by the *sftp.get(...);* because when I put this line

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        sftp.get(ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR + File.separator + entry.getFilename(), baos);
```

in again after the *System.out.println(entry.getFilename());*, I get the following ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1747)
    at de.postcon.SftpFileHandler.readFiles(SftpFileHandler.java:129)
    at de.postcon.VaFtp2EmMover.downloadVAFiles(VaFtp2EmMover.java:145)
    at de.postcon.VaFtp2EmMover.main(VaFtp2EmMover.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Buffer.getByte(Buffer.java:148)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Buffer.getString(Buffer.java:188)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1675)
    ... 3 more
```

Solution:

```
public Map<String, byte[]> readFiles () {
    final Map<String, byte[]> vaFiles = new HashMap();
    final Channel channel;
    try {
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        final List<String> ftpAccounts = Arrays.stream(this.ftpAccounts).collect(Collectors.toList());
//            final List<String> ftpFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String ftpAccount : ftpAccounts) {
//                System.out.println(ftpAccount);
            try {
                try {
                    final SftpATTRS attrs = sftp.stat(ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // The folder ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR does not exist.
                    // Simply continue...
                    continue;
                }
                final Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + "*");
                final List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> ftpFileList = files.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                final List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> entries = new ArrayList();
                for (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry lsEntry : ftpFileList) {
                    if (lsEntry.getAttrs().isDir() &&
                        lsEntry.getFilename().equals(XXX_DIR)) {
                            sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + lsEntry.getFilename() +
                                    File.separator + "*", new ChannelSftp.LsEntrySelector() {

                                @Override
                                public int select (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry) {
                                    final Matcher mtc = pattern.matcher(entry.getFilename());
                                    final SftpATTRS attr = entry.getAttrs();
                                    if (mtc.find() && !attr.isDir() && !attr.isLink()) {
                                        // gather the files to be read...
                                        entries.add(entry);
                                    }
                                    return CONTINUE;
                                }
                            });
                    }//end if
                }//end for lsEntry

                // store the gathered files...
                for( final ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : entries) {
//                        System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
                    try {
                        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        sftp.get(ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR + File.separator +
                                 entry.getFilename(), baos);
                        vaFiles.put(entry.getFilename(), baos.toByteArray());
                        logger.info("File " + ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR + File.separator + entry.getFilename() + " downloaded.");
                        baos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SftpException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }//end for
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vaFiles;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean *"I get a "Handle closed""*? Do you get an exception? What exception? What is its callstack? + Can you show us [mcve]? It looks to me that 90% of your code is not related to your problem. Do you get the same problem if you simply do `sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + XXX_DIR +                                    File.separator + "*", ...)`? I.e. without the outer loop. What's the point of the outer loop anyway? Why do you loop to find a subfolder, if you know its name upfront anyway?

Comment: Also do not use `File.separator`. SFTP always uses forward slash, not matter when the local platform path separator is.

Comment: Sorry. I put the stacktrace to the question. I'll try a minimal call...

Comment: I have an array of folders to traverse above. In each of these folders there may be a folder XXX_DIR. Hence, I have to loop over this array and look for any files in the XXX_DIR folder matching a given pattern.

Comment: OK, but my question still stands. Do you get the same error, if you simplify the code to a single call of `.ls` with the selector for a specific path.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite probable that the `selector` cannot make calls back to the `ChannelSftp`.

And you do not need that anyway.

Why don't you process the files the same way you process the subfolders?

```
final Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftp.ls(ftpAccount + File.separator + "*");
final List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> ftpFileList = files.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
for (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry lsEntry : ftpFileList) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It seems so. 
Now I only do collect the filenames in the LsEntrySelector's select method into a List<LsEntry> and get the files in a subsequent loop using this list.

Comment: Even that seems like an overkill, why don't you loop the `Vector` returned by the other overload of `.ls` instead of creating your own?